# Empty minified React app, why is it already to big?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, size, bundle

I created a **very basic** app, that only loads json from url and then displays it. **There are no chunks to split**, things get minified, but I still get the message:

"WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance. Assets:  output_react.js (245 KiB)".

The mode production is on (script is minified, during dev its over 1mb), app basically doesn't do anything and webpack already reports it as too big? Why? And how can I solve this? (style.scss is also empty, only 150 chars).

My code:
App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
require('../styles/style.scss');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      orders : []
    }

      this.getOrders();
  }
  getOrders (){
    fetch('http://localhost/supplier/get_orders.php')
    .then(results =>{
      return results.json();
    }).then(data =>{
      let orders = data.orders.map((order) => {
        return( 
          <div key={order.order_index} className={order.status}>
            {order.sizes}
          </div>
        )
      })
      this.setState({orders: orders})
    })
  }
  render() {
    return  <div className="orders_container">{this.state.orders}</div> ;
  }
}

export default App;
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'output_react.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /git/],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
      },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /git/,
                use: [
                "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
            ]
        },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /git/,
                use: [
                  "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                  "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
              ]
          }
    ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
  ],
    watch: true
}
```

Comment: Use this command to generate a profile of your build `webpack --profile --json > stats.json`. Then use `webpack-bundle-analyzer` to open and view the profile file (`stats.json`). You can also upload this file and share it here, you might want to remove any code you don't want to share though because this file will contain code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to divide the min file into chunks. Just go for lazy loading based on routes and divide it into chunks.

Comment: Please try giving examples of how tos to make this more useful.

Comment: It could also be vendor-app bundle split for a simple app with no routes.

Comment: If you have .maps.js  after build onto production, please remove them.

Comment: it is solved, @hazardous idea of using webpack-bundle-analyzer showed that bootstrap is the heavy thing. Before I only removed it from imports, but seeing that the bootstrap indeed is a problem I now removed it also from production dependencies. It might be silly for you, but for me it was not that obvious to do, I just start on webpack and react (as you probably noticed) so I got suprised of the size even after "removing" bootstrap from imports.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @hazardous. I have done the stats.json, and this is what the webpack-bundle-analyser showed:
[image: webpack-bundle-analyser result]

So it seems the bootstrap is the problem. I acctually thought this might be the reason, so I've removed only the 
**import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';** from my index.js
and this only lowered the size by 40kb.

But now (once I see the bootstrap is the problem indeed) I've also removed the bootstrap from production dependencies (in npm's package.json) - after this it works like a charm, "only" 100 kb for a bundle.js, which is ok considering it includes all the React.

Thank you a lot @hazardous, your answer solved the problem.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! A further optimization for global packages is to  directly use styles from CDNs so they are not included in your bundle, and all CDN benefits. Other option is to use cherry-picking for components which support it. Read about it here - https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3314-aggregating-cherry-picked-lodash-methods-in-an-application-module-in-javascript.htm.